# How do you sign to Docker for Windows so you can build images external images?

Tags: docker-for-windows

I am having great trouble attempting to build a docker image based on the `mhart/alpine-node:6.10.3` image. It requires that I go out to docker hub to get it, which requires that I login in. But I cannot. I have a docker ID. I can login to the `hub.docker.com` and `cloud.docker.com` via a browser. However I cannot login either via the docker cli or via the systray for Docker for Windows. What is the trick here? cli says sonnection refused and Docker for Windows login dialog just does nothing and both the boxes are outlined in red.

I've spent hours on this....grrrr...

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try "Docker logout" and "Docker login"?

Comment: I'm having the issue both with the CLI (`docker login`) and the GUI (via the sys tray for Docker for windows). I did try `docker logout`, just in case. Alas, I wasn't logged in to get logged out.